# Algorithm for summing all subsets?

Tags: summation

Given a set of integers, is there an algorithm that returns the sum of all the subsets?  For example if $s = \{6, 3, -2\}$ then the algorithm returns $28$. I.e:

$$(-2) + (3) + (3-2) + 6 + (6-2) + (6+3) + (6+3-2) = 28$$

The runtime of this is $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$ though I believe: is there a quicker way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Every element of the set occurs in half of the subsets of $s$, so in $2^{\lvert s\rvert-1}$ subsets (taking the complement gives a bijection between the subsets of $s$ containing $x$ and those not containing it). Therefore,

$$\sum_{M \in \mathcal{P}(s)}\left(\sum_{x\in M} x\right) = 2^{\lvert s\rvert-1}\cdot\sum_{x\in s}  x,$$

which computes the sum in $O(\lvert s\rvert)$ time (assuming the arithmetic operations take constant time).

Check: $s = \{6,3,-2\}$, $\lvert S\rvert = 3$, so

$$2^2\cdot (6+3-2) = 4\cdot 7 = 28.$$

Comment: Computing an exponential in binary should never be assumed to be constant, since the size of the output is so large.  Otherwise +1 ^_^

Comment: $2^n$ is easy in binary. Okay, it takes $O(n)$ and not $O(1)$ if you leave the machine types.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating the [Power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of some set $S$ with $n$ elements (denoted $\mathcal{P}(S)$) and then summing over all of the elements, so it would be impossible to have a runtime better than $\mathcal{O}(2^{n})$ because you need to generate and iterate over all of the $2^{n}$ possible subsets.

Comment: You don't need to generate the power set to find the sum.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved using a basic generating function technique. The ordinary generating function $f(z)$ where $[z^q] f(z)$ represents the number of times the sum $q$ occured among the subsets is given by $$f(z) = \prod_{x\in S} (1+z^x).$$
We want to turn $[z^q] f(z)$ into $q$, so we differentiate and set $z=1$ to obtain
$$\left. f'(z)\right|_{z=1} 
=  \left. \prod_{x\in S} (1+z^x)\times \sum_{x\in S} \frac{xz^{x-1}}{1+z^x} \right|_{z=1}
= 2^{|S|} \times \sum_{x\in S}\frac{x}{2} = 2^{|S|-1} \sum_{x\in S} x.$$